# Add second SSD to dual boot laptop

Tags: dual-boot, ssd

I have a 256GB SSD with dual boot (Ubuntu and Windows 10). Now I want to add an extra 500GB SDD along with the previous one. My question is what I need to do after inserting the new SDD. Also, is it possible to remove Ubuntu from the previous SDD and use the two SDDs for two separate OS?

Comment: After inserting the new SSD, you need to screw the lid back, and power on. ...and yes, it is possible two has two OSs on separate SSDs.

Comment: What will happen to the partition in new SSD?

Comment: Nothing particularly interesting will happen to "the partition in new SSD". It might get auto-mounted on start up, which depends on the relevant settings.

Comment: Just to add that I have 2 drives with Windows and Ubuntu on each one. That way if the small possibility of drive failure should occur, I'll always have a system available to use.